# Check Jsonobject for Int

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, string

I have a problem, I get a Json. The data comes in a dictionary.

This is a sample json:

```
Receivedtext: {
  "x": "pricef",
  "b": "usd",
  "ds": [
    "tpr",
    "avgp",
    "mcap",
    "ppc7D",
    "ppc12h",
    "ppc4h",
    "ppc24h"
  ],
  "data": [
    [
      "ADA/USD",
      "0.819",
      "21.23B",
      "6.09",
      "-5.45",
      "-5.36",
      "-10"
    ],
    [
      "AVT/USD",
      "5.968",
      "35.81M",
      "24.33",
      "-4.51",
      "-3.3",
      "6.65"
    ],
    [
      "BAT/USD",
      "0.946",
      "unknown",
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null
    ],  [
      "FUN/USD",
      "0.000",
      "0.00",
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ] ]
}
```

Normally the json should be all String. I can handle the nill/null but I dont know how to handle if its Int/Double.

If it is a Int/Double I want to replace the value with "unknown".

This is my code so far:

```
struct JsonMaintableWebsocket {
    let tpr: String?
    let avgp: String?
    let mcap: String?
    let ppc7D: String?
    let ppc12h: String?
    let ppc4h: String?
    let ppc24h: String?


    init(json: [String?]) {
        self.tpr = json[0]
        self.avgp = json[1]
        self.mcap = json[2]
        self.ppc7D = json[3]
        self.ppc12h = json[4]
        self.ppc4h = json[5]
        self.ppc24h = json[6]
    }

    static func fetchJsonWebsocketMaintable(json: Data) -> [JsonMaintableWebsocket] {
        var jsonWebsocket: [JsonMaintableWebsocket] = []
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json, options: []) as? [String: Any?]
            if let data = jsonData!["data"] as? [[String?]] {
                for d in data { 
                    jsonWebsocket.append(JsonMaintableWebsocket(json: d))
                }
            }
        }
        catch let error{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return jsonWebsocket
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `tpr`? `avgp`? How do you expect anyone to read your code?/

Comment: Please try to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry, how would it be better readable? these are my variables I want to get from the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could handle this would be to `map` over the array and check to see what kind of value is stored, and act accordingly.  You might change this part:

```
if let data = jsonData!["data"] as? [[String?]] {
  for d in data { 
    jsonWebsocket.append(JsonMaintableWebsocket(json: d))
  }
}
```

to this:

```
if let data = jsonData!["data"] as? [[Any?]] {
  for d in data { 
    let adjustedArray: [String?] = d.map({
      //First, check to see if object is nil, and return nil if so
      if $0 == nil {
        return nil

      //Check to see if value is string, and return string
      } else if let stringValue = $0 as? String {
        return stringValue

      //Otherwise return "unknown"
      } else {
        return "unknown"
      }
    })
    jsonWebsocket.append(JsonMaintableWebsocket(json: adjustedArray))
  }
}
```

It would also be easy to handle `Int` or `Double` as Strings as well, by adding a couple more options:

```
if let data = jsonData!["data"] as? [[Any?]] {
  for d in data { 
    let adjustedArray: [String?] = d.map({
      if $0 == nil {
        return nil
      } else if let stringValue = $0 as? String {
        return stringValue
      } else if let intValue = $0 as? Int {
        return "\(intValue)"
      } else if let doubleValue = $0 as? Double {
        return "\(doubleValue)"
      } else {
        return "unknown"
      }
    })
    jsonWebsocket.append(JsonMaintableWebsocket(json: adjustedArray))
  }
}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark this answer as the solution so other people know the problem is solved.